# Is there a word for the definition of an acronym?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, acronyms

I can describe "IMHO" as an acronym for "in my humble opinion."  How can I describe the reverse processes of translating the acronym into the actual phrase?  That is to say, if "IMHO" is the acronym, what do we call "in my humble opinion"?

Comment: Err, a "full form"? Yes I know it's two words, can't think of any.

Comment: IMHO is not an acronym, unless it is pronounced as if it were a word (i.e. like "im-ho", not "Eye Em Haitch Owe"). Just FYI.

Comment: @Marcin: That's definitely true, technically speaking. However, many (if not most) people seem to use *acronym* for both acronyms and initialisms, such that it is getting harder and harder to argue that the distinction holds anymore.

Comment: Especially since initialism is such a horrible word to say.

Comment: There have been many goods answers to [this similar question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/52918/22407).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The spelled-out form of an acronym or initialism (that is, "what it stands for") is called its expansion.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym_and_initialism

Comment: Yup, definitely "expansion".

Answer (score 5):

I think you might have answered your own question: *definition* is probably the best word, though *expansion* could also work (because an acronym is a type of abbreviation).