# What is the opposite of "abbreviation"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms, abbreviations

What is the opposite of "abbreviation"?

For example, if "ELL" is an abbreviation for "English Language Learners",
then "English Language Learners" is a(n) <sub>_______________</sub> for "ELL".

I'm looking for a word that will work for all abbreviations, not just acronyms, so another example would be: if "abbr." is an abbreviation for "abbreviation", then "abbreviation" is a(n) <sub>_______________</sub> for "abbr."

Comment: Does it matter that your example is for an acronym, not an abbreviation?

Comment: @bishop You are right, it is an acronym. I see acronyms as a subset of abbreviations, and I'm looking for an antonym that will work for abbreviations as well.

Comment: @bishop: Many would claim that ELL isn't an acronym if it's pronounced 'ee-ell-ell', but rather an initialism. The strict definition for 'acronym' insists that the abbreviation has been accepted into the lexicon as an uncapitalised word in its own right, for example radar, laser and scuba, though many people consider _all_ abbreviations pronounced as words, such as ISA and NATO, to be acronyms.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Whose strict definition?  My googling only required an acronym be comprised of initial letters.  [Around here](http://www.learnnc.org/lp/pages/760), "ELL" is pronounced as a single syllable.  http://ell.stackexchange.com might clear it up officially.

Comment: @bishop: [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acronym) states: 'Acronyms are treated as words in their own right and are written in lower case (such as scuba or radar).' Though the article isn't consistent, this spells out the 'strict' definition. The 'loose' definition would include say TNT and  BBC, as the article states. The 'intermediate' definition includes radar, RAM, but not BBC.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Indeed, I checked [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/acronym) and it does require an acronym be pronounceable, but not that it be lower case.  I wonder where Wiktionary gets the lower-case requirement?  (They had no source for that claim.)

Comment: @bishop: RHK claims it's a post-1939 coinage. I'd say some of these more recent words (some of the ones that don't rapidly become extinct) are used in different ways by different universities, say, and the different senses persist to confuse. 'Lexeme' springs to mind. Rather older words with conflicting / overlapping / whatever usages (in the language domain) are _complement_, _clause_ and _idiom_. I'm with the 'adverbs modify verbs only' faction, as another example.

Comment: Related/ Possible Duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/52918/14666

Comment: *full form*, *expansion* https://www.google.com/#q=abbreviation+antonym

Comment: The opposite of abbreviated is "spelled out".

Comment: Obviously, it's "noitaiverbba"!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'd go with *expansion* if I were forced to fill in the blank (although I'm more comfortable with *expansion of* than *expansion for*).  You can *expand* an acronym.

However, it would be more usual to say:

> What does ELL ***stand for***?

Or:

> ELL ***stands for*** English Language Learners.

Especially in non-technical contexts, *stand for* sounds more natural to my ear.

Comment: "Expansion" corroborated in [the formal definition](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/abbr) of the HTML `<abbr>` tag.

Answer (score 10):

It is called the *full form* of an abbreviation.

Comment: Googling `abbreviation "full form"` seems to corroborate this from several, though perhaps not official, sources.

Comment: This is what I thought of too, but I suppose I've been conditioned by [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FullForm.html).

Answer (score 8):

I've always gone with the somewhat lengthy but accurate "long form."

Comment: Well, it would be rather inappropriate if the "long form" had a short name, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Avner Shahar-Kashtan: How could it be shorter than the abbreviation?

Answer (score 5):

I would just say that the long form is the *meaning* of the short form.

> ***Q. What does abbr. mean?***
>
> A. abbr. is an abbreviation -- it means abbreviation.

Answer (score -1):

The opposite of *abbreviation* is *elaboration*.

Answer (score -1):

Could it be **augmentation**?

> The action or process of making or becoming greater in size or amount.